# What are the levels of Islamic scholarship?

Tags: islamic-scholar

What is the highest level of Islamic scholarship and how does one acquire it?  Is it a mujtahid mutlaq?  I hear many terms mujtahid mutlaq, mujtahid, Mufti, mufasir, muhadith etc

Wouldn’t you have to be a mujtahid mutlaq be a mufasir or a muhadith since you should know a lot of Hadith if you are going to write a thafsir or give verdicts.

Would people like syed Qutb and Abdullah Yusuf Ali be considered anything considering they were not scholars I believe yet they wrote thafsirs.

Many people do a 3 year degree at Islamic universities, what level of scholarship/title are they given?

And what type of study/how long do you typically need to get the various levels of scholarship?

Salam

Thanks

Comment: There's ijtihad on one side and tafsir or hadith science are only specific disciplines. So quoting them in one sentence doesn't make much sense. University studies - as mentioned - might not even give you the level of a student of Islamic science at least not necessary from a classical point of view. Because the basis is excellence in qur'an (100% memorization of at least one riwaya) and Arabic language. Once achieved you could start your studies.

Comment: @Medi1Saif but doesn’t the one doing ijtihad have to know hadith science in depth as well as quran(so be capable of being a mufasir and muhadith) since otherwise how can he pass verdicts without knowing both well?

Comment: Not all ahadith nor all the qur'an is related to fiqh topics. In fact imam a-Shafi'i said that the fiqh related ahadith are a bit more than 500+. If we accept that the amount of Sahih hadith is 4300+ you may get an idea on how much is the content of hadith one needs (certainly all madhhabs also relay on less sahih narrations), but just to see how much shari'a related rulings make of the whole.